# 'Failed to initialize monitor' when trying to run any wine applications

Tags: multiple-monitors, wine, games

The following error is being produced when trying to run any application through wine, including winecfg:

```
0050:err:x11drv:X11DRV_InitMonitor Failed to initialize monitor
0050:err:x11drv:X11DRV_InitMonitor Failed to initialize monitor
```

For some reason it's writing it twice. The audio is still being played, so if it's a game I can hear it, but it's not detecting a display. Running echo `$DISPLAY` gives me `:0.0`. Just checked Proton through Steam, and it doesn't appear to have an issue.

Running on (x)Ubuntu 20.04, wine version 6.0.2, often multiple monitors but sometimes just one. This began happening with wine 5.0.4, and I upgraded to 6.0.2 to see if that would fix the issue, and it didn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to 'fix' this by deleting the original .wine directory. Running `winecfg` again prompted wine to rebuild the directory back to default settings, now no longer getting the `initialize monitor` error message.

This method might not be optimal for anyone else suffering this problem, so make a backup of the original .wine directory before deleting it. You'll at least having a working wine configuration.